# Can I redirect people to the correct store view based on IP?

Tags: multistore, store-view, geoip

I am using GEOIP to redirect customers to either the US site or the UK site, but recently the client wanted to have the flags at the top of the site for the customers to manually switch to the US or UK site if they get on the wrong site.

But having an issue, I can only get the store flags if I put both the US and UK store views in the same store name, see pic

[image]

If I was to give US site its own store name with its own store view the flags would disappear.

I've seen several GEOip magento plugins some on github some on the magento connect store but if anyone knows of any that will allows me to redirect people to the specific store view name based on IP location.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In which magento version you work ?

Comment: Im using 1.9.0, if an update is needed I can do that

Comment: you can try :  https://amasty.com/magento-geoip-redirect.html

Comment: preferably free or open source :/

Answer (score 0):

Not that I've tried it yet, but this seems to be a free alternative to what you're looking for:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/redirect-visitors-by-country-ip.html

You can input the redirect url aka. your store view URL based on whether it's USA or UK.

Let me know if this helped, as I'll be implementing something similar for one of my clients soon.